# How to check if a browser supports <input type="time" />

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

Is there a way in HTML, javascript, or Razor to detect if the browser supports `<input type="time" />` elements?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Invalid values will be rejected when assigned to the `.type` property of an `input` element.

```
try {
    var input = document.createElement("input");

    input.type = "time";

    if (input.type === "time") {
        console.log("supported");
    } else {
        console.log("not supported");
    }
} catch(e) {
    console.log("not supported");
}
```

If there's some browser issue I'm not aware of, then using `.innerHTML` should do the same.

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "<input type='time'>";

if (div.firstChild.type === "time")
    console.log("supported");
else
    console.log("not supported");
```

Comment: What about IE @cookiemonster?

Comment: @kehrk: Just tried it with IE8, and it threw an exception. Excellent.

Comment: Not worried about IE8, only the latest version. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Ah, I do remember IE throwing on invalid `type` values. I'll update with a try/catch. Thanks.

Comment: @cookiemonster: I didn't mean that to say this wasn't a good answer. Throwing an exception suggests to me that the browser doesn't support it. :-) I'm surprised (but pleased) to find that between an exception and getting back `"text"`, detection seems possible. I wonder why [Modernizr says they can't detect it](http://modernizr.com/docs/#inputtypes).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yes, I understood what you meant. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: The section you linked is *"Modernizr cannot detect that date inputs create a datepicker, the color input create a colorpicker, and so on—it will detect that the input values are sanitized based on the spec."*, which, as I understand, means that Modernizer cannot guarantee that a `color` input is really rendered as a color picker, but it can detect whether `color` is a valid `type` value (based on the sanitation).

Comment: I read it the same way Felix did...that it can detect the field, but not what the browser does with the field.

Comment: About the exception, it's not because IE8 doesn't accept invalid types (it does, they're just rendered as text types): it's because you can't change the `type` property of an `<input>` field in IE8- after it's been created (or even the `name`, but it doesn't throw an exception in that case). You can, however, use `document.createElement("<input type='time'>")`... which of course isn't supported in other browsers and IE9+.

Comment: @MaxArt: You can actually change it in IE8 but only to a valid type, only once, and only if the `input` hasn't yet been added to the DOM. So basically, you can create a new Element node like normal and set its `type` a single time to a recognized value before appending it.

Comment: @cookiemonster Ah, cool. So it's IE11 in IE8 mode that's playing tricks on me. Tried with IE8 on a VM and it's like that (can change the `name` too). What a perverse mess...

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option would be to check the browser support and code the usage programmatically.

http://caniuse.com/input-datetime

Comment: It's best to feature-test rather than browser-test.